# ChartJS formatear tooltips

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Tengo un grafico en chartjs que me muestra cantidades sin formatear en los `tooltips`. Al pasar el mouse me muestra bien los valores formateados. Pero quiero que los `tooltips` siempre sean visibles, pero al hacerlos se muestran sin formato.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código del grafico:

```
// Sales graph chart
const salesGraphChartCanvas = $('#line-chart').get(0).getContext('2d')

const salesGraphChartData = {
  labels: piecesDays,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Total Importe',
    fill: false,
    borderWidth: 2,
    lineTension: 0,
    // spanGaps: true,
    borderColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,0.8)',
    pointRadius: 3,
    pointHoverRadius: 7,
    pointColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(60,141,188,1)',
    data: Object.keys(allDataForChart).map(name => allDataForChart[name]),

  }]
}

const salesGraphChartOptions = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    display: true,

  },
  hover: {
    animationDuration: 0
  },
  animation: {
    onComplete: function() {
      const chartInstance = this.chart,
        ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

      ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(
        13,
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle,
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily
      );
      ctx.textAlign = "center";
      ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

      this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
        const meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
        meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
          const data = dataset.data[index];
          ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
          ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 2);
        });
      });
    }
  },
  tooltips: {
    enabled: true
  },
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';

        if (label) {
          label += ': ';
        }
        label += new Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR', {
          style: 'currency',
          currency: 'ARS'
        }).format(tooltipItem.yLabel);

        return label;
      }
    }
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'DÍA'
      }

    }],
    yAxes: [{
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'CANTIDAD'
      },
      gridLines: {
        display: true,
        // color: '#efefef',
        drawBorder: false,


      },
      ticks: {
        min: 0,

        // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return value.toLocaleString('es-AR', {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'ARS'
          });
        }
      }
    }]
  },

}

new Chart(salesGraphChartCanvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: salesGraphChartData,
  options: salesGraphChartOptions
})
```

Alguna solución de como formatear los `tooltips` que están siempre visibles?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Yo ocupo el siguiente código para que los tooltips siempre estén visibles, prueba a ver si te funciona

*VA DENTRO DE OPTIONS*

```
option:
{
 "animation": {
                            "duration": 1,
                            "onComplete": function() {
                                var chartInstance = this.chart,
                                    ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

                                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                                this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
                                    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                                    meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                                        var data = dataset.data[index];
                                        ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        },
}
```